# Select ids from posts with eloque

Tags: php, laravel

How to get posts in Laravel and show them on index.blade page but with different ID's of previous posts. In controller I have this code

```
$posts=Tblnewsarticles::limit(5)->get();
return view('index', ['posts' => $posts]);
```

Now I need more posts but with differents ID's than in `$posts` variable

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is [pagination](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/pagination)

Use:

```
$posts=Tblnewsarticles::paginate(5);
return view('index', ['posts' => $posts]);
```

For the links to the post pages, add the following to your index.blade.php:

```
{{ $posts->links() }}
```

Comment: Hmm..No I don't wan't pagination. Becouse those posts will be show on sidebar in index.blade. So I want them with different's ID's then posts in the middle of page.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you can use `paginate` method in query builder from: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/pagination#paginating-query-builder-results

```
public function index()
{
    $posts = Tblnewsarticles::order_by('id', 'desc')->paginate(5);

    return view('index', ['posts' => $posts]);
}
```

> PS: It would be more helpful if you see how pagination works.

Hope this helps :)